# Is it possible to make NAnt command-line properties read-write?

Tags: nant

By default, properties defined on the NAnt command line are read-only, even ignoring the `overwrite="true"` attribute.  Is there any way to make them read-write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same problem yesterday. Since I couldn't find a solution, I ended up renaming the command line arguments. Somewhat cumbersome but at least it works.

I was passing in property `repo.name` via `-D:repo.name=MyRepo` and tried this:

```
<property name="repo.name" value="${repo.name}/MySubrepo" />
```

That gave me a warning and the assignment was ignored. So I changed the name of the command line argument to `repo.name.orig`.

```
<property name="repo.name" value="${repo.name.orig}/MySubrepo" />
```

Would that be possible for you as well?

Comment: This is a good workaround.  For my purposes, I'll have to add a conditional to the assignment so that *repo.name* can be assigned both ways: `if="${repo.name == ''}"`.  This should allow me to call the script from both the command line and a [call target](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/tasks/call.html) during an automated TeamCity build.  Thank you!